# Frequency count of characters in String for a given start and end index in Java

Tags: java, string

How to determine the numbers of characters found in a String between a given begin and end index in O(1) time complexity?

There can be a pre-processing step like storing in HashMap which can have O(n) time complexity.

Can anyone suggest how to retrieve the character count using 0(1) time complexity after pre-processing? The O(1) time complexity is for retrieving the count of any input character with a start and end index

Eg: String stackoverflow.
Character count a between index 1 and 6 is 1
Character count o between index 1 and 6 is 1
Character count o between index 7 and 12 is 1
Character count o between index 0 and 12 is 2

All these must be retrieved using 0(1) time complexity.

Comment: If you want `O(1)` (amortized), then it sounds like you're basically completing the task ahead of time and then just referencing the result. Starting from just the input string, you would need to check every character from the start to end indices, there's no magical way around that without additional info (e.g. if the string was sorted).

Comment: Unlike the title, your first paragraph doesn't say anything about frequency count.  But this sounds more like `What is the preprocessing algorithm and structure which would permit the lookup of a set of preprocessed strings in constant time?`, which was already alluded to in the comments.

Comment: Another possibility would be for any given string and indices, `memoize` the result where it could be checked first.

Comment: @WJS, I could save the indices and the occurrence of characters during the preprocessing stage as a list in a map. When I need to pull the count of character for a specific index range, I would still need to iterate through list for the specific character and do summation. In worst case, if the string is made up of only the character then again it would be O(n) and not O(1).

Comment: @Alice Yes, I know.  Buy you will have to either preprocess it all at once or as you need it.  But you can't do a frequency count for variable string sizes in constant time.  Imagine a substring of length 10 and one of length 10_000.